# Using pattern matching to filter array

Tags: swift

this is my code:

```
enum SymptomPeriod {
    case Day
    case Night
}

enum SymptomType {

    case Breathing(SymptomPeriod) 
    case Breathlessness(SymptomPeriod) 
    case Opression(SymptomPeriod) 
    case Cough(SymptomPeriod) 

    case ActivityLimited() 
    case SecureTreatment() 
}

struct Symptom {
    let type: SymptomType
    let date: NSDate
}
```

And i have an array of symptoms.

```
let symptomList: [Symptom] = ...
```

My need is to filter the list of symptoms with the SymptomPerion criteria, i trying to do like this:

```
 let daySymtoms = symptomList.filter { (symptom) -> Bool in
    return symptom.type = ???
 }
```

My problem is in the filter function.

(My goal is to use a filter function and not a loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few suggestions

### Use your struct as namespace

Instead of repeating the word `Symptom` (e.g. `SymptomPeriod`, `SymptomType`) you should put your enums into you `Symptom` struct

### Rename SymptomType as Kind

Once you moved `SymptomType` into `Symptom` you can drop the `Symptom` part of the name. However using `Type` as name will create a conflict so you should rename it `Kind`.

### Add the period computed property to Kind

This will make the filtering much easier

### Here's the code

```
struct Symptom {
    enum Period {
        case Day
        case Night
    }

    enum Kind {
        case Breathing(Period)
        case Breathlessness(Period)
        case Opression(Period)
        case Cough(Period)

        case ActivityLimited()
        case SecureTreatment()

        var period: Period? {
            switch self {
            case Breathing(let period): return period
            case Breathlessness(let period): return period
            case Opression(let period): return period
            case Cough(let period): return period
            default: return nil
            }
        }
    }

    let kind: Kind
    let date: NSDate
}
```

### The solution

Now the filtering has become very easy

```
let symptoms: [Symptom] = ...
let filtered = symptoms.filter { $0.kind.period == .Day }
```

Comment: Very nice. But there is a lot of `case XXXX(let period): return period`. I wish Swift had a way of avoiding such repetition.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i am doing it:

```
let daySymtoms = symtoms.filter { (symptom) -> Bool in
            switch symptom.type {
            case .Breathing(.Day), .Breathlessness(.Day), .Opression(.Day), .Cough(.Day):
                  return true

            default:
                  return false
            }
         }
```

Let me know if you have more simple way to do it.